# complex script shaping for Devanagari fonts

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

Is there any project available for shaping complex scripts of Devanagari fonts in C#?

Regards,
James

Comment: What do you mean by "shaping"?

Comment: I mean the rendering method/rule. http://people.w3.org/rishida/docs/unicode-tutorial/part3

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used Devanagiri fonts in C#. Using Unicode in handling your characters makes sure your complex scripts are rendered properly. I'm not aware of any rendering rule you need to write in order for the fonts to "shape" properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but providing this answer to ensure someone who is searching is pointed in the right direction.

Latest versions of Windows ship with Uniscribe - which handles all of the complex-script shaping. Uniscribe and OpenType fonts go hand-in-hand.

For majority of the cases, especially on Windows, you don't have to worry about all the nitty-gritty details - but in some cases you need to.

In those cases, you will find the information at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091(v=vs.85).aspx and also at: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/uniscribe-mysteries valuable.